# Cannot install python3-pip on kali linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, kali-linux

There is an error  : it says there is no install candidate for  python3-pip

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us more information?

Comment: did you tried to see if pip3 is installed on your kali machine, it should be installed by default , run `pip3 --version` to check

Comment: Also can you update your question and add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` it's important , so we can answer your question

Comment: Would be a good idea to provide an English translation so non-turkish readers could help you out.

Comment: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/56152)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should check if `pip3` is installed on your system . To do so run the following :

```
pip3 --version
```

if it's already installed you should get something like :

```
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

in this case `pip3` is already installed and you don't need to do anything .

Otherwise `python3-pip` Package is in `kali-rolling` repos , And to install it you need to make sure you have `kali-rolling` enabled in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` , by running following in your terminal :

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list

apt update && apt upgrade
```

then finally you can install `python3-pip` by running :

```
apt install python3-pip
```

This should get `python3-pip` installed on your kali machine

If for some weird reason this didn't work for you and you needed a quick way to install pip3 on your machine you can download this file : [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Then run this in your terminal :

```
cd ~/Downloads 

python3 get-pip.py
```

This should get `pip3` installed on your machine , you can check by running `pip3 --version`

Answer (score 1):

What about adding this ppa repo and updating the OS? also be sure your kali install in connected to internet.

`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install python3.6`